# How to solve 'MongoError: $where is not allowed in this atlas tier'?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I had the following query which was working in my local mongodb but when I switched to atlas, its giving me

MongoError: $where is not allowed in this atlas tier

I looked at similar post, but could not find answer

```
await Markertag.find( { $where: 'this.markerNum.toString().match(' + search.searchText + ')' }).distinct('photoId');
```

Answer (score 1):

[Unsupported Commands in M0/M2/M5 Clusters](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/unsupported-commands/).

> The following commands exhibit special behavior in `M0` Free Tier and `M2`/`M5` shared starter clusters:
>
> ...
>
> `distinct` - The `$where` operator is not supported.
>
> `find` - The `$where` operator is not supported.
>
> ...

You should either upgrade your tier to paid one, or chose another MongoDB provider.